# Is it possible to change Ghost CMS comment styles?

Tags: comments, ghost-blog

I've been trying for days now, the problem that I see is that Ghost CMS does not appear to utilise any of the custom themes styles for comments. This is because it loads the comments in an iframe (why, WHY!?), and uses its own CSS stylesheet.

Does anyone have any ideas how to improve this and ensure your comment section looks like the rest of your site? Currently on my site it's completely unusable.